# How to list installed Chocolatey packages using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, chocolatey

**Aim**

Compare installed chocolatey package with latest available version on [Chocolatey Gallery](https://chocolatey.org/), install (`cinst packageName`) latest if latest version > installed version.

**Problem**

Code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354602/how-to-get-java-output-with-ruby) which works for `java -version` has been used to read the output from `clist -lo`.

```
command = "clist -lo"

require 'open3'
Open3.popen3(command) do | stdrin, stdout, stderr|
  p stderr.read
  p stdout.read
end
```

Nor `stderr.read` neither `stdout.read` returns the output while the command prompt does. The path variables are correct. Executing `clist -lo` using cmd on a default path returns the list of installed Chocolatey Packages.

**Question**

How to get the output from `clist -lo` using Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can use `capture3` instead of popen3 to capture the output.

```
command = "clist -lo"

require 'open3'
stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(command)

puts "stdout: #{stdout}"
puts "stderr: #{stderr}"
puts "status: #{status}"
```

results in

```
stdout: 7zip.install 9.22.01.20130618
autohotkey_l 1.1.13.01
autohotkey_l.install 1.1.13.01
chocolatey 0.9.8.23
ChocolateyGUI 0.11.1
ConsoleZ 1.9.1.13351
cyg-get 1.1.0
cygwin 1.7.23.20130814
expresso 3.0.4334.20120225
git.install 1.8.3
Listary 4.02.1360
PowerShell 3.0.20121027
putty 0.63.0
ruby 2.0.0.24700
TeraCopy 2.27
Reading environment variables from registry. Please wait... Done.
stderr:
status: pid 47528 exit 0
```

for me